# How do the Blutsauger's and the Amputator's passive health regeneration modifiers stack?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

- The Medic, by default, passively regenerates +3 health per second.
- The Blutsauger decreases this: –2 health per second.
- When active, the Amputator increases this by +3 health per second.

Now, I usually have both the Blutsauger and the Amputator equipped at the same time, meaning that my passive health regeneration should be +4 per second with the Amputator active, and +1 per second otherwise.

However, in reality, I notice that, sometimes, if I switch to the Amputator and then switch back to my Blutsauger, I will passively regenerate +4 health per second (despite the fact that the Blutsauger is the active weapon, and not the Amputator). Even stranger, I sometimes regenerate +6 health per second when the Amputator is active (as if I didn't have the Blutsauger equipped).

This begs the question: what are the criteria for the Blutsauger's –2 passive health regeneration per second (i.e. does it have to be active in order for this effect to apply), and, similarly, what are the criteria for the Amputator's +3 health regeneration per second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The amount of health a Medic passively regenerates is also affected by how recently he was damaged.  The +3 health per second is the "recently damaged" healing rate.

Over the next 10 seconds of taking no damage, the Medic's self-heal rate [increases](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medic) until it hits +6 health per second.  Note: Fire and Bleed are damage, so don't think this will save you from those two statuses.

Incidentally, this increased healing rate after not taking damage also [applies to being healed by a Medigun](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Healing#Healing_and_.C3.9CberCharge_rates)... and to all 9 classes in this respect.  This is why sometimes you seem to heal classes faster than normal.  According to the wiki, this goes from normal to triple healing rate between 10 and 15 seconds out of the patient being out of combat.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know this about medic's heal rate.  Does it apply immediately when the player has spent that much time outside battle?  Or does it only apply if you re-connect your Medigun?

Comment: @Zibbobz Since it ramps up, its hard to say.  Most of the time when you actually see the increased healing with the Medigun, it's on a Scout as they're the only ones fast enough to escape the front without having to inflict self-damage to do so (rocket/sticky jump).

Comment: Does this health regen stack? So, if I were to have the Syringe Gun, any medi gun, and the Amputator, with the Amputator being active and not having been hit in 10 seconds, would I gain +9 per second?

Comment: @alexqwx It *should* but I've never tested it.

Comment: @Powerlord By the way, I've been meaning to ask: how does one test things like damage, speed, health regen, etc.? Are there dedicated servers for it, or what?